# How to apply fadeIn and fadeOut effect to a select control based on parent and child checkbox selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, fadein, fadeout

I'm having a select control which should be hidden when the form loads. I'm having a parent checkbox and a group of child checkboxes. What I want to achieve is unless the parent checkbox or at least one(or more than one) of the checkbox from the child checkboxes is checked the Select control should not be shown, it should be kept hidden. If the parent checkbox or any one(or more than one) checkbox among the child checkboxes is checked the select control should be shown. One more condition to display the select control is the field with id **site_id** should contain the value XYZ only. If it has some different value then the select control should not be displayed even after selection of parent checkbox or any one or more than one checkboxes from child checkboxes. My code snippet is as follows:

```
<!--The code below is for parent checkbox-->
<input type="hidden" value="XYZ" id="site_id" name="site _id">
<p class="custom-form">
 <input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="" id="ckbCheckAll">
 <a class="drop" href="#">more</a>
</p> 
<!--Parent checkbox code ends here-->
<!--The code below is for select control-->
<select name="select_option">
  <option value="0">--Select Action--</option>
  <option value="1" class="delete_user" href="#deletePopContent">Delete User</option>
  <option value="2" class="disable_user" href="#disablePopContent">Disable User</option>
  <option value="3" class="update_user" href="#updatePopContent">Update Class and Section</option>
  <option value="4" class="default_user" href="#defaultPopContent">Change Password</option>
</select>
<!--Select code ends here-->
<!--The code below is for child checkboxes-->
<input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="" value="d3c1ac9ac08da86e73258a11a43251af">
<input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="" value="b993166c4795b3bfe96640e55e8dcbbc">
<input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="" value="77d4721ada7677feda77a250c7cee1c4">
<input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="" value="68d6e7a8c09c77c5fec49945beaea4f8">
<input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="" value="85634bc9cdbcb6b39eaf4946b99db5de">
<input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="" value="bb1a20794d65966b950c5933100496ce">
<input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="" value="59ee376a9d126a26b350fff3110ea825">
<input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="" value="428895b1ae5f3226345e6c6f256c7c85">
<!--In the same manner other child checkboxes will come-->
<!--Child checkboxes code ends here-->
```

Can you help me in this regard, please? Thanks in advance.
The jQuery code for checking all checkboxes upon checking the parent checkbox is as folows:

```
$("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () { 
  $(".ez-checkbox input").toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked);
    if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)'))
      $(".ez-checkbox input").removeAttr('checked');
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $(".ez-checkbox input").attr('checked','checked');
    $(".ez-checkbox input").closest("div").toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked);;
});
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you show us your Javascript code?

Comment: @Nunners:I've modified my question with jQuery code I've written to select and deselect all the child checkboxes upun onchange event of parent checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps... I've modified your HTML to include a div around the child checkboxes, as well as an ID field for the hidden select box:

```
<!--The code below is for parent checkbox-->
<input type="hidden" value="XYZ" id="site_id" name="site _id">
<p class="custom-form">
 <input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="" id="ckbCheckAll">
 <a class="drop" href="#">more</a>
</p> 
<!--Parent checkbox code ends here-->
<!--The code below is for select control-->
<select name="select_option" id="hiddenSelect">
  <option value="0">--Select Action--</option>
  <option value="1" class="delete_user" href="#deletePopContent">Delete User</option>
  <option value="2" class="disable_user" href="#disablePopContent">Disable User</option>
  <option value="3" class="update_user" href="#updatePopContent">Update Class and Section</option>
  <option value="4" class="default_user" href="#defaultPopContent">Change Password</option>
</select>
<!--Select code ends here-->

<!--The code below is for child checkboxes-->
<div id="childBoxes">
    <input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="" value="d3c1ac9ac08da86e73258a11a43251af"/>
    <input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="Checkbox1" value="b993166c4795b3bfe96640e55e8dcbbc"/>
    <input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="Checkbox2" value="77d4721ada7677feda77a250c7cee1c4"/>
    <input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="Checkbox3" value="68d6e7a8c09c77c5fec49945beaea4f8"/>
    <input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="Checkbox4" value="85634bc9cdbcb6b39eaf4946b99db5de"/>
    <input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="Checkbox5" value="bb1a20794d65966b950c5933100496ce"/>
    <input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="Checkbox6" value="59ee376a9d126a26b350fff3110ea825"/>
    <input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="Checkbox7" value="428895b1ae5f3226345e6c6f256c7c85"/>
    <!--In the same manner other child checkboxes will come-->
</div>
<!--Child checkboxes code ends here-->
```

Your javascript above wasn't clear to me, in that it seems to be trying to toggle checkbox displays, but is otherwise unrelated to your question. However, here's a solution to the problem you stated:

```
<script>
    $('#hiddenSelect').hide();
    if ($('#site_id').val() == "XYZ") {

        $("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () {
            displaySelect();
        });

        $('#childBoxes :input').click(function () {
            displaySelect();
        });

        function displaySelect() {
            var childChecked = $('#childBoxes').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
            var parentChecked = $('#ckbCheckAll').is(':checked');

            if (childChecked.length > 0 || parentChecked) {
                $('#hiddenSelect').show();
            } else {
                $('#hiddenSelect').hide();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: After reading the title of your question, you can use $('#hiddenSelect').fadeIn('400') or $('#hiddenSelect').fadeOut('400') instead of .show and .hide, to the same effect.